# Lemmatizing text works on physical devices, but not Xcode previews, simulators, or tests

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Lemmatizing text works on physical devices, but not Xcode previews, simulators, or tests. This code works on physical devices (Mac, iOS 16.4, iOS 17.3) but not on Xcode previews, simulators, or Xcode tests.

```
import SwiftUI
import NaturalLanguage

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(lemmatize())
        }
    }
  
  func lemmatize() -> String {
    let text = "Pumpkins grow slow. Cars are fast."
    
    let tagger = NLTagger(tagSchemes: [.lemma])
    tagger.string = text

    print (tagger.tagSchemes)

    var lemmaText: String = ""
    
    tagger.enumerateTags(in: text.startIndex..<text.endIndex, unit: .word, scheme: .lemma) { tag, range in
      let stemForm = tag?.rawValue ?? String(text[range])
      lemmaText += stemForm
      return true
    }
    
    return lemmaText
  }
}
```

Given the string "Pumpkins grow slow. Cars are fast.”, I expect -> “pumpkin grow slow. car be fast.”. However, I get the string back unmodified on the simulators (multiple iOS versions). Running on latest Xcode and Sonoma.

Comment: I don't see the part where you first check the `availableTagSchemes` method. Not all tag schemes or languages are available everywhere.

Comment: @matt Good point. Thanks. Checking the availableTagSchemes does show that Lemma is missing on the simulators in Xcode 15.2. On a machine running Xcode 14.3, the Lemma tag scheme does exist. So the simulators (ios16.4 for example) between the two Xcodes are different.

Comment: If the lemma scheme is not present for the target language, then your code behaves as expected and there is no question to answer.

Answer (score 1):

As per comment by @matt, the Lemma Tag scheme isn’t available in iOS simulators in Xcode 15.2.

Since this is a new behavior (vs Xcode 14), I’ve filed a feedback with Apple. I don’t know if the change by Apple is intentional or an error.

To be specific, checking available tag schemes for English results in:

```
(Xcode 15.2, iPhone 14 Pro, iOS 16.4 simulator)

Language
Script
TokenType

(Xcode 14.3, iPhone 14 Pro, iOS 16.4 simulator)

Language
Script
TokenType
NameType
LexicalClass
NameTypeOrLexicalClass
Lemma
```